# mapbox.getStyle() returns null when changing maptype

Tags: java, android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I have a problem with mapbox when changing the mapStyle from Style.MAPBOX_STREETS to Style.SATELLITE_STREETS (and vice versa) quickly in a row. (This happens with other styles too, those are just examples)

My code:

```java
public void btnChangeMapType(View view) {
    this.mapboxMap.getStyle(style -> {
        String styleUri = this.mapboxMap.getStyle().getUri();
        if (this.animator != null)
            this.animator.cancel();

        if (styleUri.equalsIgnoreCase(SATELLITE_STREETS)) {
            changeMapType(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS, this.mapboxMap.getStyle());
        } else {
            changeMapType(Style.SATELLITE_STREETS, this.mapboxMap.getStyle());
        }
    });
}
```

```
private void changeMapType(String mapboxMapType, Style mapboxStyle) {
    this.mapboxMap.setStyle(mapboxMapType, style -> {
        if (this.previousLocation != null) {
            this.positionGeoJson = new GeoJsonSource(MAP_LAYER_SOURCE_ID, Feature.fromGeometry(Point.fromLngLat(this.previousLocation.getLongitude(), this.previousLocation.getLatitude())));
        } else {
            this.positionGeoJson = getNewGeoJsonPosition();
        }

        if (this.hasFocus && this.animator != null) {
            drawDrivenLine();
            this.animator.start();
        }
    });
}
```

And if i click on a Button that calls ***btnChangeMapType*** quickly multiple times i get an error on Line ***String styleUri = this.mapboxMap.getStyle().getUri();*** in btnChangeMapType()

Error Log:

```
2020-02-20 11:31:50.828 14916-14916/at.myprojects.project E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver: Exception in onDidFinishLoadingStyle
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.Style.getUri()' on a null object reference
```

Is there a way too keep my app from crashing/having this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `String styleUri = this.mapboxMap.getStyle().getUri();` , the `getStyle()` is not needed because you're already in the `getStyle()` block that returns a `Style` object above that line (the `style -> {`). So it'd be `String styleUri = style.getUri();` instead. I think this will solve the `NullPointerException` message.

Also, it doesn't look like you're using the `Style mapboxStyle` parameter anywhere, so you can remove that from `changeMapType()`.

Comment: Great! Glad to hear it.